# why are there so many crazy lines on my model's head when sculpting while using the mirror modifier?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, mirror, sculpt, mirror-modifier

I am trying to sculpt a cute little goblin and for some reason my mirror modifier seems to be making life harder for me.

1. There are these crazy lines on the goblin's head: [image]
2. Why does the goblin's nose have a weird line running through it even when I try to draw over it?
   [image]
3. Am I using the modifier wrong because all my issues seem to be deriving from it: [image]

Comment: it's the Mirror modifier axis I guess, apply the modifier and use the sculpt symmetry option instead

Comment: Those "weird lines" are evidence of _Z-fighting_ (faces overlapping). Blender can't tell which one to display in "front" so it shows that buzzy artifact instead. Whenever you see those lines, it means you have 2 faces occupying the same space, in your case, likely due to the mirror modifier. Make sure you are mirroring on only the axis you need, and make sure not to cross the "center line" unless you have clipping and/or merge enabled. You may have some luck by selecting the whole mesh in edit mode then pressing M (merge) and selecting "by distance".

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thanks, the craziness went away!! Do you recommend using the mirror modifier for sculpting or is there something easier that can help me reach symmetry with the rest of my character?

Comment: I generally use the mirror modifier to get the base model (the part that is symmetrical), then I apply the modifier and use sculpting for the finer details and the asymmetric parts. For example, I would model a whole head using the mirror modifier (because both sides are roughly the same), and then when I gave the general look, I would apply the modifier and use sculpting to detail it (like making the sides slightly uneven, and adding wrinkles and such).